# Accurate javascript decimal number processing with Google Closure Compiler & Library

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal, google-closure-compiler, floating-accuracy

I'm 6 months into a project using google closure library and compiler. I'm finding I'd like more accurate decimal number handling (handling some simple currency calculations)
one of the common problems I run into are things like:

`(1.005).toFixed(2) != 1.01`

I haven't found any relevant modules in the closure library documentation, I have tried the BigDecial library (https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) as well as bignumber.js (https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) and related projects. They all work well, but don't work when compiled with `--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` (they don't have the annotations required by the compiler).

- Is there a method in the google closure library of handling arbitrary precision decimals, or at least more greater precision floating point numbers?
- Is there an external library that will work with closure compiler with advanced_optimizations?
- Is there a time effective way to adapt one of the libraries above to work with the compiler and advanced_optimizations?
- Are there any other solutions I may not have considered for more accurate floating point numbers in JavaScript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This question will get closed by the community for this reason: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Thanks T.J. - I have updated my question trying to follow your guidance.
I hope I have described the problem well. While the solution need not be an external library, I suspect it may be. I would appreciate any more specific guidance as to which aspect of my post makes my question ineffective on stack overflow.

Comment: Your question would be more appropriate on the [closure-library-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/closure-library-discuss) or [closure-compiler-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/closure-compiler-discuss) google groups.